# Visual Studio referencing namespaces that don't exist anymore

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

While I've been making an MVC project with ASP.NET, I've renamed folders etc over time, and for some reason visual studio will still think the files are still stored there with the old name.

For example if I declare a class object that i've made, it will find it, but it will ask me to add like "using.FolderName.Class" when I've since renamed "FolderName" to "Folder" or even made a new folder and moved the class into it. The solution still builds, and everything works. But It's kind of worrying to see it's trying to reference something that's not there anymore. What's going on here? should I be worried?

Comment: make sure all your names are updated in .csproj file as well

Comment: No probably you forgot to rename the `namespace` behind it

Comment: Folders are not the same as namespaces.  Renaming the folder does not change the namespace of classes inside that folder.

Comment: @BJMyers, I don't think he really thought of folders. I think he just wanted to give an example and used folders as example name. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes it was an example. But also BJ Myers' comment was relevant, I changed the folder names forgetting to change the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your source code files for the lines that look like

```
using System;

namespace MyProject.MyFolder {
}
```

renaming folders won't automatically change the namespace. You could do it automatically with visual studio by right clicking on the folder and choosing  `Adjust all namespaces in folder`, or by right clicking on the namespace and choose to rename the namespace

Comment: I don't have a context menu option for `Adjust all namespaces in folder`.  Is that coming from an extension you have installed?

Comment: @BJMyers Probably I have it with Resharper installed ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll make sure all namespaces are correct. That should have been the first thing I checked :D